# Why does the VS.NET Designer for my ASP.NET pages show "response is not available in this context" for all controls?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a VS.NET solution that was originally a 3.5 VS.NET 2008 solution, now upgraded to VS.NET 2010 .NET Framework 4.0. I *rarely* use the 'Designer' tab to preview the generated controls of my ASP.NET pages, but in this instance I want to to see the wizard of an Object Data Source Control.

Now ALL of my pages (content pages of a single simple Master page) show the message "response is not available in this context" for all of my controls.  I tied deleting the page from my project, adding a *new* page, and copying back in the source and code; same error. I also tried cutting out controls 1 at a time, and clicking "Refresh" in the designer but I can't find out the problematic issue. Remember every single page in my solution does this.

Any ideas on what causes this error?

Comment: Have you tried clearing out your .NET temporary build directory in the windows folder? Sounds like your cache isn't being cleared. e.g. C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. I cleaned out all (3) of the following 'Temp' cache directories and then restarted VS.NET:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

C:\Users\\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer and detailed it in the link below:

**Workaround For VS.NET ASP.NET Design Tab Not Rendering Controls:**
http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2011/02/workaround-for-vsnet-aspnet-design-tab.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading any kind of support code that is outside of the web context you will get the error:

The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context

To fix this, go to the line where you have your Response.Write and change it to:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Test");
```

Comment: I don't use Response.Write in any of my pages. Regardless that would probably be something done on a per page need for code like that, and this is ALL of my pages. It has been like this for several months now; I just decided to try and figure out the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issue. It turns out that a single .aspx page(without master page), a single HTML page, and a content page ALL work well **IF** I omit inheriting from my custom PageBase.aspx which all pages inherit from.  Hence we may have found the culprit.

My PageBase has methods and functionality common to all pages, and therefore all .aspx pages inherit from it.  There must be code within it that is causing the issue.  The interesting thing is that the excat code dind't cause issues in VS2008 but does now in VS2010 so there must of been an update as to how the rendering engine works to view the auto generated page.

I believe I found the culprit code in the following  (abbreviated method) that overrides the OnInit() for all of my pages:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As EventArgs)

   If Not (Context.Session Is DBNull.Value) Then

   End If

End Sub
```

If I comment out the method above, Clean and Rebuild the solution, and proceed to look at the 'Design' tab, it works.

**So my question now is** there a more streamlined way other than remembering to comment/uncomment that code so that the design tab will work regardless? I am thinking how there are #IF statements for debuugung, etc. for skipping code during debugging, and wondered if there was anything like this or any configuration that would ignore that code at design time?

Comment: The DesignMode property looks promising, but this issue is not applicable to a single control but rather code in the OnInit (as shown above) that all pages inherit.  How would I marry the 2 pieces together?